# Wordpress pages address rewrite

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

## **UPDATE**

I tried using the internal wordpress rewrite. What I have to do is an address like this:

```
http://example.com/galleria/artist-name
```

sent to the `gallery.php` page with a variable containing the `artist-name`.

I used these rules as per Wordpress' documentation:

```
// REWRITE RULES (per gallery) {{{
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array','wp_insertMyRewriteRules');
add_filter('query_vars','wp_insertMyRewriteQueryVars');
add_filter('init','flushRules');

// Remember to flush_rules() when adding rules
function flushRules(){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

// Adding a new rule
function wp_insertMyRewriteRules($rules)
{
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['(galleria)/(.*)$'] = 'index.php?pagename=gallery&galleryname=$matches[2]';
    return $newrules + $rules;
}

// Adding the id var so that WP recognizes it
function wp_insertMyRewriteQueryVars($vars)
{
    array_push($vars, 'galleryname');
    return $vars;
}
```

what's weird now is that on my local wordpress test install, that works fine: the gallery page is called and the `galleryname` variable is passed. On the real site, on the other hand, the initial URL is accepted (as in it doesn't go into a 404) BUT it changes to `http://example.com/gallery` (I mean it actually changes in the browser's address bar) and the variable is not defined in `gallery.php`.

Any idea what could possibly cause this different behavior?

Alternatively, any other way I couldn't think of which could achieve the same effect described in the first three lines is perfectly fine.

---

## Old question

What I need to do is rewriting this address:

```
(1) http://localhost/wordpress/fake/text-value
```

to

```
(2) http://localhost/wordpress/gallery?somevar=text-value
```

Notes:

- the remapping must be transparent: the user always has to see address `(1)`
- `gallery` is a permalink to a wordpress page, not a real address

I basically need to rewrite the address first (to modify it) and then feed it back to mod rewrite again (to let wordpress parse it its own way).

**Problems**

if I simply do

```
RewriteRule ^fake$ http://localhost/wordpress/gallery [L]
```

it works but the address in the browser changes, which is no good, if I do

```
RewriteRule ^fake$ /wordpress/gallery [L]
```

I get a 404. I tried different flags instead of `[L]` but to no avail. How can I get this to work?

EDIT: full .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^fake$ /wordpress/gallery [R]

RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: [L] means "last", so you don't get any other rules after the first one.  The reason the first one doesn't act as "Last" is because the inclusion of the hostname forces the request to go back to the browser.  Keep in mind that rewrite rules are applied in order, and only a single pass is made over the rules, so if your /wordpress/gallery URL needs to be rewritten, put the rule to do so AFTER the RewriteRule you show above.

Comment: (I can't provide a 'real' answer without seeing the entire list of RewriteRules.)

Comment: Added full list of rules

Comment: I don't think you can do this in your .htaccess file because Wordpress uses the original URL (i.e. '/wordpress/fake/text-value') to determine what to do with the request. I think you'll probably need to add your own rules to Wordpress's internal rewrite system, see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Rewrite

Comment: Richard: yes I tried that, and it works on my local install, but for some reason the site I'm working on works differently (it's stuffed with every kind of plugin) so I was looking for a rewrite solution instead of coping with that mess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, it was the [Permalink Redirect](http://scott.yang.id.au/code/permalink-redirect/) plugin which needed to be configured to skip the desired "virtual" URLs, else it would issue a 301 Permanently moved.

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^fake/([^/]+)$ gallery?somevar=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Nope, that's the first thing I tried and it just ends in a 404 from wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the very-delayed answer here, but I believe what you need to do is what Gumbo suggested but with [the addition of the passthrough/PT flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> This flag forces the rewrite engine to set the uri field of the internal request_rec structure to the value of the filename field.
> ...
> You must use this flag if you want to mix directives from different modules which allow URL-to-filename translators.

Although Wordpress (via mod_php) runs after mod_rewrite is done, it normally gets the original (pre-rewrite) uri, and it uses that to do its own internal rewriting, rather than the re-written filename value.

So try:

```
RewriteRule ^fake/([^/]+)$ gallery?somevar=$1 [QSA,PT]
```

I added QSA so that, just in case someone went to /wordpress/fake/something?page=3, it will get passed along properly.  Let me know how that works.

Comment: I tried PT too, but it doesn't help. I believe the only way to do it is via wordpress' internal rewrite as Richard M said in a comment.

Answer (score -1):

1. Using your favorite HTML/PHP editor, open `wp-admin/includes/misc.php`
2. Find function function `got_mod_rewrite` Its around line 18 or so.
3. Comment out the existing function: `/* this is commented out */` — You can delete this function if you are sure the solution works, but to be safe, just comment it out in case you need to put it back.
4. Add the following instead:

   ```
   function got_mod_rewrite() {
       $got_rewrite = true;
       return apply_filters(‘got_rewrite’, $got_rewrite);
   }
   ```
5. Save and upload.